# i18n localization issue; cannot initialize i18n library in Backbone javascript page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internationalization

i'm pretty new to javascript / Backbone.js and totally new to i18n localization. I have to use i18n to begin the localization of a complex site. I have no clue how to use i18n to do this. The i18next.amd-1.5.10.js library is included in the project, but there is no way i can initialize it and later on use it. I noticed that all the required libraries are included in the login page's definition, except i18next, like so:

```
define([
```

'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'backboneForms',
  'message',
  'auth',
  'models/LoginModel',
  'views/footer/FooterView',
  'text!templates/login/loginTemplate.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, BackboneForms, message, AuthModel, LoginModel, FooterView, loginTemplate, i18n)

also, there has been an older attempt to use this library for localization, but it didn't work and the initialization code has been commented out:

```
var LoginViewModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {}
});

var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: undefined,
    el: $("#container"),
    //i18n: t.initialize('login', 'loginTemplate').i18n,
```

How can i use i18n to localize the site, given i can't even initialize it? How can i successfully initialize i18n and use to localize the login page?
Thanks,
Octavian

Comment: Maybe and old question of me can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796727/marionette-i18n-in-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to init i18next. Somewhere in your project you will bootstrap the application and start backbone. You might want to start backbone after i18next is initialized:

```
i18n.init(options, function(t) {
  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Now you could use i18next:

- use the jquery function `$(mySelector).i18n();`
  http://i18next.com/pages/doc_jquery.html#jqueryfc
- get resouces for a template using the objectTree functionality
  http://i18next.com/pages/doc_features.html#objecttree
- or use some advanced template helper http://i18next.com/pages/doc_templates.html